# Max of a coll in my sql

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, increment

I want to make a register system, to record some values from html inputs in a Database, I use the following query:`INSERT INTO Search (id, username, fname, lname, age, fullname) VALUES ('?', '$username', '$fname', '$lname', '$age', '$fullname');`

But I don't know how to increment the id every time when submit a name:

[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3k1oS.png)
I want something like:

id
""""""""""""""""
1
max+1
new max+1

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql+auto+increment

Answer (score 0):

You don't; you make it an auto increment column ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html ) and then you don't specify it in the insert statement, and mysql will calculate the next value to put in automatically

Answer (score 0):

When creating your table, you should specify the id column to AUTO_INCREMENT like so:

```
id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

you can alter your table at this point.

You should definitely not do this by hand IMO.
You should also consider declaring it a PRIMARY KEY.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following:

`ALTER TABLE Search
    CHANGE COLUMN id id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST,
    ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);`

or execute two queries:

`SET @max = 0;
INSERT INTO Search 
   (id, username, fname, lname, age, fullname) 
VALUES 
   (@max:=@max+1, '$username', '$fname', '$lname', '$age', '$fullname');`

Comment: Run me through the part where you made the id auto incremental, but then specified it anyway in the insert?